# How to write a search query in android SQLite database?

Tags: android, sql

In SQL I use :

```
select * from Table_name  where col_name like 'ex'
```

What is the equivalent to the above query in sqllite android. 
I have tried this in rawQuery(...), but it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
Cursor res = dB.rawQuery ("select * from Record where name like 'comp'"+"");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will be like below

```
try {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String _Query = "SELECT * FROM " + _Table_Name;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(_Query, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                    // here you get the data on each row.

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("", "exception : " + e.toString());

    }
```

Comment: It is working only for 1 row ..I have many rows in my database but it only checks the first row and stops after that, how to slove this problem

Comment: select * from table_name is only returning one row ..how to move to next row and so on..